# Nearest Neighbor search in PostGIS using cases

Tags: postgis, postgresql, nearest-neighbor

I am using the following PostGIS nearest neighbor query to determine how close a point is to an area (polygon) that has been flooded and it's working well:

```
SELECT 
     ST_AsText(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700)),
     "flooding".gid, 
      ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700),
         "flooding".geom) AS distance
FROM
  "flooding"
WHERE "flooding".geom && ST_Expand(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700), 400)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700), "flooding".geom) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

However I would like to categorize the distance as follows and then output the result:

```
CASE
  WHEN distance > 300 THEN 'OUTSIDE'
  WHEN distance > 50 AND distance  <= 300 THEN 'CLOSE'
  WHEN distance < 50 THEN 'INSIDE'
END as flood_result
```

I know I need to use the "case when else" format to accomplish the above conditional statement, however I do not know how to do this with regard to ST_Expand.

Comment: I would use ST_DWithin rather than ST_Expand, after creating the point once in an initial CTE, eg, `WITH point (geom) AS (SELECT  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700)`, as it is cleaner, and you can then refer to it in later queries rather than constantly recreating it. As far as the CASE is concerned, you need to put `CASE WHEN distance > 300m THEN 'OUTSIDE'`. Note you need single quotes, not double.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I added `WITH point_loc AS (
 SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700)
 )` however when I used point_loc later, I get a syntax error. I noticed that point_loc is no longer a geometry but text, is that the problem?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça, also do you know how to save the distance from the WHERE statement so I can use it in the CASE.. END section?

Comment: What do you see when you run: `WITH point_loc (geom) AS ( SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700) )
SELECT st_geometrytype(geom) FROM point_loc;`

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça, I ran the above command and got: st_geometrytype (text): ST_Point. So it's text. I so ran the code below and got ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" at the last SELECT.

Comment: The code below was missing a ) after ST_DWithin (feel free to fix it yourself, like I said untested). If you look at the documentation for [ST_GeometryType](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryType.html) it takes a GEOMETRY TYPE and returns a TEXTUAL representation of said geometry. That does not mean it is a text string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this query cleaner by putting you point in an initial CTE, and then using ST_DWithin, rather than recreating a point form text, which will mean the spatial index isn't using on floods, if you have one, which you should for any non-trivial table.

Also, you can make the case statement a bit simpler, as you don't need between logic and you can use ELSE at the end.

```
WITH 
   point_loc (geom) AS ( 
     SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700) ),
   distances (gid, distance) AS (
     SELECT  
        fl.gid,
        ST_Distance(fl.geom, p.geom) AS distance
      FROM
         point_loc p, flooding fl
      WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, fl.geom, 400))
   SELECT 
      gid,
      CASE WHEN distance > 300 THEN 'outside'
           WHEN distance > 50 THEN 'CLOSE'
           ELSE 'INSIDE'
       END as flood_result
      FROM distances;
```

This is untested, but I believe close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@JohnPowellakaBarça, your solution worked, there was just a missing closing parenthesis:

```
WITH 
  point_loc (geom) AS ( 
    SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(531673.0, 180848.2),27700) ),
  distances (gid, distance) AS (
    SELECT  
      fl.gid,
      ST_Distance(fl.geom, p.geom) AS distance
    FROM
      point_loc p, flooding fl
    WHERE ST_DWithin(p.geom, fl.geom, 400) )
  SELECT 
    gid,
    CASE WHEN distance > 300 THEN 'OUTSIDE'
         WHEN distance > 50 AND distance <= 300 THEN 'CLOSE'
         ELSE 'INSIDE'
    END as flood_result
  FROM distances;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, I put it in the comments that I had corrected it.

Comment: Sorry missed that comment.